# Double.ToString is loosing the precision of double value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, precision

I just wanted to know why the following code

```
Convert.ToDouble("866666666.6666666666666666667")
```

gives output:

> 866666666.66666663

And

```
Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble("866666666.6666666666666666667"))
```

gives output :

> 866666666.666667

[image]

Comment: Well why don't you try `Convert.ToString("866666666.6666666666666666667")` and you'll find out

Comment: [1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx) "Using the ToDouble(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Double.Parse(String) method.", [2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx): "Ordinarily, if you pass the Double.Parse method a string that is created by calling the Double.ToString method, the original Double value is returned. However, because of a loss of precision, the values may not be equal."

Comment: whoever is downvoting, could you give little hint why this is happening. I know it's because of precision loss but not able to understand why convert.tostring causing precision loss

Comment: I think it's because of this: The string representation of a double is in base-10, so there's naturally a loss of precision. If the string representation simply showed the base-2 32 bits as 1's and 0's then you wouldn't lose any precision, in a sense. The loss of precision is from the change of base.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre it gives same value.

Comment: @Quantic basically second code is converting value 866666666.66666663 to string, no? ideally it should give this value only.

Comment: Are you sure.  I don't get the same results as you.

Comment: @Paparazzi please check the value in watch. I have just added screenshot.

Comment: @Mukund Look, Whenever the you use `Convert.ToDouble` the value have to be stored in an eight-byte place named variable although it is inside the scope of the method and temporal. The mentioned 8-bytes can store a number of predefined values. Think of 10.1 and 10.2. There are _finite_ values between these values. A small portion of these values can be shown. And there is also another thing which is named rounding. When a floating point number can not be shown as it is, this concept is used for showing that number.

Comment: But your the two writeline give the same value.   Somehow ToString() to not write out he full precision.  And precision of double is not perfect.

Comment: @Paparazzi would you edit. Although English may not be your first language, I can not read

Comment: @Paparazzi yes because writeline first convert the value into string then writes it on console. I am trying to understand the behavior of Double.ToString method but not able to understand it properly.

Comment: Your question is not clear on this is a string formatting versus imprecise precision.

Comment: @Paparazzi String is using it's default formatiing

Answer (score 2):

This appear to be a string formatting issue
With "R" and "G20" I get the same as what you see in watch
The 20 is total number of digits
{0:F20} was not correct - it just added a bunch of zeros
[Double.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Double d = Convert.ToDouble("866666666.6666666666666666667");
Debug.WriteLine(d);
Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("G"));
Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("G20"));
Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("R"));
Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F20}", d));
string s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble("866666666.6666666666666666667"));
Debug.WriteLine(s);
```